# Back reference in Wikipedia

Tags: links, wikipedia

Say an entry A has a cross-reference pointing to entry B. Is there any chance that given entry B, we can know it is referred by entry A (any probably other entries)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about internal links between Wikipedia articles, known as "[Wikilinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Link#Wikilinks_(internal_links))" or "internal links". You can see which articles link to a specific article by using the "What links here" tool. On desktop, there's a link to this tool in the left sidebar, in the "tools" section. I wasn't able to find an easy way to access the tool from an article if you're using the mobile version of Wikipedia, but the tool [is available here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere).

If I was wrong to assume you meant internal links, and instead you meant links to Wikipedia articles used as references in other articles: that *shouldn't* happen, because [Wikipedia is not a reliable source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source), and thus shouldn't be used as a reference in other Wikipedia articles.